# Reorganizing data in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am in the process of creating a macro using VB that will reorganize columns and determine column order of headers.

The code below works fine but once I run the code, I am prompted to type in the name of the Sheet that I wish to use:'Specify the name of the sheet that needs to be reorganized' (Answer: 'Sheet1')

Can you tell me is there anyway I can run the below code without Excel prompting me to enter the name of the Sheet that I wish to alter the data on?

```
'REARRANGE COLUMNS IN EXCEL BASED ON COLUMN HEADER
Sub MoveColumns()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

'CONSTANT VALUES
data_sheet1 = InputBox("Specify the name of the Sheet that needs to be reorganised:")
target_sheet = "Final Report"
iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

'CREATE A NEW SHEET TO STORE THE RESULTS
Worksheets.Add.Name = "Final Report"

'ORGANIZE COLUMNS
For iCol = 1 To Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'SETS THE TARGETCOL TO ZERO IN ORDER TO PREVENT OVERWRITING EXISTING TARGETCOLUMNS
    TargetCol = 0

    'DETERMINE COLUMN ORDER
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "billing_country" Then TargetCol = 1
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "partner_accountname" Then TargetCol = 2
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "partner_number" Then TargetCol = 3
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "pbl_due_date" Then TargetCol = 4
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "total_amount" Then TargetCol = 5
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "pb_payment_currency" Then TargetCol = 6
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "sort_code" Then TargetCol = 7
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "cda_number" Then TargetCol = 8

    'If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
    If TargetCol <> 0 Then
        'Select the column and copy it
        Sheets(data_sheet1).Range(Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol), Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, TargetCol)
    End If

Next iCol 'Move to the next column until all columns are read

End Sub
```

Comment: don't use `InputBox`?

Comment: I see what you mean but I just copied this code from somewhere (I am new to VB!) and I when I try and remove the inputbox, it won't work. Is there any other methods other than inputbox that you are aware of? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 methods come to mind to not have a prompt appear.

One is to define the sheet within the function. e.g.

```
data_sheet1 = "Sheet1"
```

in place of the `data_sheet1 = inputbox(...` line.

the other is to pass the sheet name into the function, e.g.

```
Sub MoveColumns(data_sheet1 as String)
```

and then completely remove the `data_sheet1 = inputbox(...` line. You will have to change the code that calls the routine from `MoveColumns` to `MoveColumns "Sheet1"`, but then you can put any sheet names you want, and call it many times. e.g.

```
MoveColumns "Sheet1"
MoveColumns "budget"
MoveColumns "MyVeryLongSheetName2047"
```

Comment: The first part: data_sheet1 = "Sheet1" worked perfectly, thanks for your help!